# Magento 2 | Display Catalog prices for specific groups without Tax

Tags: magento2, product, price, tax, price-rules

I'm currently experiencing a weird problem on my Magento 2.2.6 Store. While giving some customer-groups a 0% Tax Rule the prices on the catalog get still displayed with tax, even tho the "tax info text" says its 0%. Am I missing a configuration or do I miss configure something? Cross-Border Trade setting is "off"

---

I've attached 2 images to visualize the problem a bit better. The first picture shows the price without tax inside the shopping cart ( thats how it is supposed to be ). The second image shows the product at the catalog ( including tax ).

[image]

---

**EDIT 25.10.2018**
I had the idea that it was probably an issue from my custom theme but after checking that in comparison with the default Luma Theme I can confirm that this issue still exists.

---

**EDIT 26.10.2018**
I thought I had an issue in my taxrules but that look correct  for me, i'll attach an image of the configurations below:
[image]

---

**EDIT 29.10.2018**
As wished I upload the Rates.csv for you guys to take a look at it:
http://www.sharecsv.com/s/65c899e359d20a9033efb56b01b9eea9/rates.csv

Basically all 0% Tax-rates are assigned to the "tax free" Customer groups.

Comment: Can you export your TAX rule class share in your post it for better understand.

Comment: ive  added the export

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, has anyone found the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration for showing catalog prices with or without tax, you should set it to  **Excluding Tax**

*Admin=>Store=>Settings=>Configuration=>Sales=>Tax=>Price Display Settings=>Display Product Prices In Catalog*

[image: Magento 2 catalog tax settings]

If you got that config correct and it's still showing with the taxes then you might have something else going on in your templates.

Comment: If i set it to `excluding taxes` arent all prices displayed excl. tax? Even for the normal customers ?

Comment: After you flush cache, yes

Comment: Then it doesnt work for me. I want to `NOT LOGGED IN` & `General` displayed with tax and only for specific customer groups without tax

Comment: Marcel, then you'll need to get or write a module for that - I was just answering the part of your question "Am I missing a configuration or do i missconfigure something " - sorry. The reason why it works in cart is because in the cart it's already part of a quote where tax calculations for this specific customer are taken into account

Answer (score 0):

If the customer group is added the tax rule, just don't have a tax rule for that customer group.

If there is multiple rules ensure the customer group is not on there.

Not having tax is the same as trying to set the tax to 0.

That should exclude them. For the main tax rule , you might have to manually select what is needed as it can choose all by default.