# Show hide tax based on customer group magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, tax, customer-group

Is it possible to show/hide tax for specific customer group?

Or show prices with tax and without tax based on customer group in magento2

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/247678/3024

Comment: I believe the shared link is not restricted to customer groups

Comment: It's the same concept - display price with or without tax to different customer groups

Comment: Can you please share the steps, because I believe the Settings in System > Config are global

Comment: Indeed they are. You will need a module for that.